# PuppeteerJS not taking screenshot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, puppeteer

So I've been working with Puppeteer to take screenshots from a given URL but for some reason my code below it is not working?

It keeps throwing the following error:

```
[0] Error: Protocol error (Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.width - BINDINGS: 
int32 value expected at position 22
```

That or simply returns an blank canvas/white image.

```js
exports.captureWebsite = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.body.url;
  const format = req.body.format ? req.body.format : 'jpeg';

  // If there's no URL, thrown a 500 server error
  if (url === ``) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please add an URL`, 500));
  }

  // Get dimensions
  const width = req.body.width;
  const height = req.body.height;

  // Launch browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    defaultViewport: {
      width: width,
      height: height
    }
  });

  // Open new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

  // Define properties
  // page.setViewport({
  //   width: width,
  //   height: height
  // });

  // Wait a few seconds
  // await page.waitForResponse(
  //   (response) => response.url() === url && response.status() === 200
  // );

  // Instead of taking a screenshot, convert it to base64 and return it
  const image = await page.screenshot({
    encoding: 'base64',
    fullPage: true,
    type: format
  });

  // Close browser
  await browser.close();

  // Send response to user
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ success: true, data: `data:image/${format};base64,${image}` });
});
```

I originally had `const browser = await puppeteer.launch()` only, however whenever I tried to use it with `page.setViewport(...)` the image that was being returned was always 800*600 not matter what the input from the form was.

This is code that I previously had:

```js
  // Get dimensions
  const width = req.body.width;
  const height = req.body.height;

  // Launch browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  // Open new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

  // Define properties
  page.setViewport({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });

  // Instead of taking a screenshot, convert it to base64 and return it
  const image = await page.screenshot({
    encoding: 'base64',
    fullPage: true,
    type: format
  });

  // Close browser
  await browser.close();
```

Comment: I have the same problem.. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
  page.setViewport({
    width: parseInt(width.toString()),
    height: parseInt(height.toString())
  });
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.